# Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space of dimension $n \ge1$ and let $B \subset V$ . At following statements are equivalent:

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, problem-solving, linear-independence

> a) $B$ is a base of $V$.

> b) Each element of $V$ is uniquely written as a linear combination of elements
> of $B$.

I'm a little confused, doesn't this equivalence come straight from the definition?

My attempt:

If B is the basis of V then:

Let $b_1,…,b_k \in B and v_1,…,v_n \in V$, for $k \le n$

We have that there is a unique solution to the equation $\sum_{l=1}^k \alpha_k b_k = 0$ (1)

And we also have to

$(2)
\begin{cases}
v_1 =\alpha_1 b_1 + … + \alpha_kb_k \\
. \\
. \\
. \\
v_n =\alpha_1 b_1 + … + \alpha_kb_k
\end{cases}$

From (1) we have that $v_1, …, v_n$ is uniquely written and from (2) that it generates all V.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackexchange.

We start with $(i) \Rightarrow (ii)$:

Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be a base vor $V$. Being a base means that these vectors span $V$ and are linearly independent. Let $w \in V$, we know that we can write $w$ as a linear combination of the $v_s$:

$ w = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i$

Now assume that there is another tupel $(\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_n)$ with

$ w = \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i v_i$

Substrating these two equations yields:

$ 0= w = \sum_{i=1}^n (\lambda_i-\gamma_i) v_i$

By the linear independence it follows that $\forall i=1,\dots,n:\lambda_i=\gamma_i$, therefore they are unique.

For $(ii)\Rightarrow (i)$ let every element be a unique linear combination of the $v_i$. Obviously the $v_i$ then span $V$, so we only have to proof the linear independence. Let

$0= \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i$

It also holds:

$0 = \sum_{i=1}^n 0 v_i$

Since the combination is unique,  $\forall i=1,\dots,n:\lambda_i=0$, which means that the $v_i$ are linearly independent.